# Historical dbcc checkdb results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dbcc-checkdb

Is there a better way of accessing historical `dbcc checkdb` result history (if output logging was not used at runtime) than xp_readErrorLog?

```
EXEC xp_readErrorLog {0-20}, 1, N'CHECKDB';
```

SQL Server 2008 or later.

Answer (score 4):

Method 1: Easy way

The Best way that i am using as of now is [ola hallengren's](https://ola.hallengren.com/)  SQL server Maintenance solution for  [SQL Server Integrity Check](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html).

Within this solution it gives you an option of storing the output or logging it to a table as per you're convenience:

**LogToTable**

Log commands to the table `dbo.CommandLog`.

Please read the complete web link as highlighted in above answer to know how you can make use of it:

Method 2:

To insert the DBCC results into a readable and manageable format, you can use the 'WITH TABLERESULTS' option for DBCC CHECKDB to get an output that can be piped to a table for analysis:

1) Collect the Data:- via creating a table to store the output from created SP as explained in this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2325/capture-and-store-sql-server-database-integrity-history-using-dbcc-checkdb/).

2) Schedule the job

3) Analyse the data from the table.

Also, would suggest you to read [CHECKDB From Every Angle: When did DBCC CHECKDB last run successfully?](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-when-did-dbcc-checkdb-last-run-successfully/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The ola maintenance plan is great moving forward and logging output, but didn't address my specific question about reviewing historical runs.  The 'last run successfully' would get ... well, the last successful run, but not all historical or runs that returned errors.  Years ago I wrote a script that uses that last run successfully property to automate quarterly dbcc checkdbs {no successful dbcc checkdb in +30/60/90 days}; I just never wrote the output to a table (hence the base question).  Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at the application event log. For SQL 2008 R2 instances, the event ID to filter on would be 8957 (at least for success codes).

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I used the last 20 restarts of errorLog and will use as far back as I can get the appEventLog and build out the history.  Future dbcc checkdbs will log output.